# vite, npm run build, $ is not a function

Tags: laravel, vite

Использую Vite в Laravel, подскажите, почему при запуске `npm run dev` сайт запускается без ошибок,
а если запустить `npm run build` то выдаёт ошибку `$ is not a function`?

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/js/app-adminpanel.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

**layouts/app.blade.php**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ...

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>@yield('title') | {{ config('app.name') }}</title>

    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app-adminpanel.js'])

</head>
```

**app-adminpanel.js**

```
// import 'jquery';
import './vendor/jquery';
// import $ from './vendor/jquery';
// import jQuery from './vendor/jquery';
// import jQuery from 'jquery';
// window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery
import './adminpanel';
```

`'./vendor/jquery'` - `resources/js/vendor/jquery.js`
тут если раскомментировать `import 'jquery';` вместо `'./vendor/jquery'` то выдаёт и в dev ошибку

**adminpanel.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('adminpanel ready');
})
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "sass": "^1.62.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

**Edited**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.**
Получилось устранить ошибку путём добавления в файл `adminpanel.js` содержимое из файла `resources/js/vendor/jquery.js`.
И получается что в результате в сжатом файле js находится две копии jquery (первый из файла `app-adminpanel.js`).
Можете объяснить что там произошло при сборке и почему работает только с двумя jquery?

Comment: наверно нужно что-то такое? `(function($) {})(jQuery)`

Comment: в консоли что ещё кроме ошибки есть? текстом добавьте или скрин

Comment: @InDevX добавил скрин

Comment: В консоли Вы только ошибку кинули) имел ввиду там есть от vite сообщения? Если есть то когда оно - после ошибки или до. `window.addEventListener('load', function () { console.log($); });` так отрабатывает? или свой код оберните в setTimeout на 5-10 секунд

Comment: @InDevX load и setTimeout выдает undefined для console.log($)

Comment: @InDevX vite собирает без ошибок, ошибка уже в браузере из-за jQuery

Comment: @InDevX  если собрать все js-файлы в один файл вместе с jquery, jquery ведь нужно как-то инициализировать? 
 `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.js` он ведь не вызывается здесь?

Comment: если подключить отдельно jquery, то ошибки в браузере нет <script src="/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: @InDevX добавил комментарий в вопрос, можете подсказать?

Comment: Можете на гитхаб выложить код? с ошибкой, тут надо самому смотреть